# How to enter "special" characters in the password file?

Tags: exim

What is the range of characters allowed in the password field in the `password.client` file in Exim4?

My password has the `:`, `!` and `.` characters. Are these permitted as is? If not, how do I encode them?

PS: The credentials are for Exim as a client to a "smarthost".

Comment: this question needs more details and focus

Comment: Can you say what more details you require to be able to understand or answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

`.` and `!`  should work `:` is not allowed.

It's probably possible to enable `:` by modifying the configuration file, but the code there is pretty messy so I don't want to try.

The code looks like : should work, but it doesn't.